# Use variable for Wordpress content

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to use a variable from within the content of a Wordpress Page? I'm thinking about Terms & Condition pages, Contact pages, etc., where I would want to provide a client with boiler-plate content without having to find all the instances of the site name from within the site's page content.

Something like "Thank you for signing up for [sitename]. Please use this form to sign up to the [sitename] newsletter!"

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the wordpress function [get_bloginfo()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo). It will let you hook in to many of the options set in WordPress.

For example, `get_bloginfo( 'name' )` will give you the name of the site, `get_bloginfo( 'description' )` will get you the description (defaults to "Just another WordPress blog") and so on.

You can find a full list of all the possible params in the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo).

Comment: I'm talking about the content itself, not the page template. This method would not work, it would either output the code as text, or it would output an empty string (depending on how you enter the content, Visual vs. Text)